# Using maven for code metrics

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Can I use maven for some metrics in my code ?
I want to fail the build if line of code in a method exceeded 6 lines.
Or line of code in a class is not more than 50.

Comment: You can call checkstyle from Maven.

Comment: Do you have a simple pom file for checking method not exceeding 6 line?